# "work in progress" - hiding an answer which is being formulated.

Tags: support

If I'm trying to put an answer together where should I do that? I'd guess answer the question but delete the answer. So the answer could still be worked on, but others wouldn't be bothered by trying to read a half-finished answer.

Part of the problem is that I don't have any editor that will allow me to see the markup. All the latex voodoo is relatively new to me, but I have used many mark-up languages before.

Comment: You know, if you start writing an answer, it saves a draft of it. So you could work on you question, and when it says in a small font "draft saved", you could close it and do other things.

Comment: Just tried it. If you close the page the work is gone. That is part of  what I want to avoid. With multiple windows open it is easy to close the wrong window.

Comment: Then that must be a big on your part. True, sometimes the work gets lost, but most of the time it doesn't.

Comment: It really should be saved, maybe there was some other issue. I sometimes attempt to answer a question at work and when I get home and open the question again I can see my draft. You can also open the same question in a new tab and see your progress. Please don't save/edit too many times, as this will trigger automatic flags and then we have to sort out, what and why this is happening. Another possibility is of course saving it locally as a textfile and then just copy and paste when you start again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, in fact, I agree with you. SE is supposed to save the draft; however, it has failed to do so in many of the posts I wanted to write. I have also written some long posts and will write some more.

But the saving-draft mechanism is all SE can offer. Instead, I recommend you save your own draft either in Microsoft notepad (or any other editor that doesn't process anything on text), or in an online <s>dump</s> paste tool like [Paste bin](http://pastebin.com/). Every time you get back to writing the answer, just <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (select all), then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (d'uh, copy) and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (paste) in SE's editor, and continue your work in the environment it provides.

I recommend against any editors that are heavily programmed for document layout, like MS Word. It$\,\ldots\,$has unpleasant consequences conflicting with SE's editor.

Comment: I wouldn’t call Word a text editor, anyway.